# Color picking from given coordinates

Tags: python, windows, color-picker

What is the simplest way to pick up the RGB color code of the given coordinates? For simplicity let's assume that the screen resolution is 1024x768 and color depth/quality 32 bits. The coordinates are given relative to the upper left corner of the screen. I'd like to get some tips or examples how it can be done with Python.

Comment: I guess that is platform dependant. Which platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [win32gui](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32gui.html) ActivePython documentation should be useful.
I think you can construct something like:

```
import win32gui
GetPixel(GetDC(WindowFromPoint( (XPos,YPos) )), XPos , YPos )
```